# wow64!_TEB32 not found

Tags: c++, windbg

I am trying to analyze a wow64 process dump.
The issue is memory leak, so I need to check the heap.
I am referring to this article to analyze the dump:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31382/Memory-Leak-Detection-Using-Windbg.

```
0:000> .load wow64exts

0:000> !sw
Switched to 32bit mode


0:000:x86> !heap -s
NtGlobalFlag enables following debugging aids for new heaps:
    tail checking
    free checking
    validate parameters
LFH Key                   : 0x00000000072e0d1a
Termination on corruption : ENABLED
  Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast 
                    (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
00000000001b0000 40000062    1024     32   1024      8     2     1    0      0      
0000000000320000 40001062   47808  45812  47808      7     8     7    0      0      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


0:000:x86>  !heap -stat -h 0000000000320000 
*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger   ***
***    doesn't have full symbol information.  Unqualified symbol      ***
***    resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a   ***
***    fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution ***
***    of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that   ***
***    enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol     ***
***    server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to     ***
***    appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect      ***
***    symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.     ***
***                                                                   ***
***    For some commands to work properly, your symbol path           ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: wow64!_TEB32                                  ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************
 heap @ 0000000000320000
group-by: TOTSIZE max-display: 20
    size     #blocks     total     ( %) (percent of total busy bytes)
```

Can not find wow64!_TEB32, so can not go ahead.
Is there any body whole can help on this?

Comment: Try using the 32 bit windbg.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that your [symbols are set up correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/480982), usually by doing

```
.symfix c:\symbols
.reload
```

Usually, for 32 bit applications, a 32 bit dump should be taken, if you don't want to debug the WOW64 layer itself.

However, in your case (concerning the `!heap` commands), you can just repeat the steps in the 32 bit version of WinDbg, which also runs on 64 bit Windows and which can open 64 bit dumps.

Comment: Hi Thomas, it doesn't work even if I open the dump by 32bit windbg. The result is same.

Comment: @Leon: I tried it on my machine before posting the answer with WinDbg 6.2.9200. Which version are you using?

Comment: My Windbg is 6.3.9600. I think you attach to some process, not open a wow64 process dump. If I attach to a wow64 process using 32bit windbg, all the commands can works fine. But when I open a wow64 process dump, both 32bit and 64bit windbg can not work.